# Replace some data with random generated number that follows the particular distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distribution

I have some dirty data describe the age of people. The interval is from -7000 to 2015. I have change the value by

```
df_members['bd'] = df_members.bd.apply(lambda x: -99999 if float(x)<=1 else x )
df_members['bd'] = df_members.bd.apply(lambda x: -99999 if float(x)>=100 else x )
```

The graph below show the data.

[image]

I plot the graph by excluding the value that is -99999

[image]

How do I replace the value of -99999 without affecting the distribution as shown in the second image? The age is in-between 15-50 years, the mean  is about 29 and median of Birth Date = 28.0. I am planning to generate random number between 15-50 but I am worrying of destroying the original distribution.

Comment: Have you looked at the location and scale parameters for the distributions available in numpy? For example, take a look at the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal) for `np.normal.random`.

Comment: well, don't you actually want to change the distribution? the distribution with the outlier -99999 included is erroneous and not actually representative of real actual values found in the sample. Just throwing it out and recalculating seems like the correct option. If you are insistent on keeping the original, erroneous distribution just change the X axis of the graph to stop before -99999 instead of changing the underlying data

Comment: @Dylan I am doing some classification work so I have to either throw away the age column which is erroneous or I can replace those values with some random values, which hopefully still maintain the distribution ( that are shaped without those error data)

Comment: oh got it. i'll write an answer in a sec

Comment: Note that the `df` tag is for the Unix command by that name and has nothing to do with dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78063/replacing-outliers-with-mean

A quick primer on why this usually isn't done. Regardless:

We will generate a new set of values with [numpy.random.normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) based on our samples mean and standard deviation, and replace anything beyond a value of our choosing with one of these new "random normal" samples.

```
df_members['bd'] = df_members.bd.apply(lambda x: np.rint((np.random.normal(bd_mean, bd_sd))) if x==-999999 else x )
```

and modify the "x==-99999" to whatever logic you need to find stuff to replace.

So, bd_mean and bd_sd can also be calculated inline with:

```
df_members['bd'] = df_members.bd.apply(lambda x: np.rint((np.random.normal(df_members.bd.mean(),df_members.bd.std())) if x>9999999 else x))
```

There are many different sample types if you feel its a non normal distribution! just look here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.random.html

Thanks to all for the edits!

Comment: The code will assign one random value to all of the rows that > 90, any idea how to make each of them has their own random value?